# Subscription protocol to Outlook REST API rich notification fails to create secure SSL channel

Tags: ssl, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have a web app which subscribes to rich notifications with Outlook REST API v2.0.

It was working well since several months, but as of 18 days ago it started to send back `HTTP 400` codes when updating or creating subscriptions. I am issuing a `POST` to:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{id}/subscriptions
```

The error code sent back in the response body of the API is the following :

> Notification URL verification failed. System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

From my server, the `POST` request with token is still received and sends back an `HTTP 200`. It is an `HTTPS` website with an SSL certificate.

Is there an update about SSL version with the Outlook REST API? Or about the protocol (the documentation doesn't mention it yet) ? What could be the reason of these sudden failures ?

Outlook webhooks subscription protocol still works on Microsoft Graph API with same parameters.

Edit : it was a problem of SSL configuration between Heroku and Cloudflare that triggers the 400 error, but only on the Outlook REST API...

Comment: If this is working with Microsoft Graph, why not simply use Graph? The two APIs should be interchangeable. As Outlook REST API ]begins to deprecate](https://dev.office.com/blogs/outlook-rest-api-v1-0-office-365-discovery-and-live-connect-api-deprecation), this is something you'll eventually need to do anyway.

Comment: Thanks @MarcLaFleur for your point. The main difference that is still not available in Graph : rich notifications. The push notification can contain much more informations (using the select) and thus manage more specific events. Hope it will come soon to the Graph API indeed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means there is a mismatch in supported SSL/TLS protocols between your server and the Outlook REST API. Try ssllabs.com to see which protocols either side supports.

Is your web app written in .NET? On versions prior to 4.6, the latest TLS protocol versions aren't enabled by default.

Comment: My app is written in Ruby on Rails, hosted on Heroku, with a SSL certificate managed by cloudflare. I get an A+ for my website with ssllabs - it supports HSTS, TLS until 1.3 version. `outlook.office.com` gets an A, with support of TLS until 1.2. As I did not change anything on my side, how is it possible that a lower level of security could result in a SSL/TLS mismatch ?

Comment: It's not clear from your post whether your app is connecting to Outlook, or the other way around: you mention "From my server, the POST request with token is still received".
The error message you posted is from a .NET application. I presume this error comes from the Outlook REST API?

Comment: Indeed sorry. My rails app makes the POST call to subscribe, which triggers a notification URL validation, the app receive the POST validation from one side, and then get the answer from the subscription endpoint from the other side. The error message is what is inside the response body, sent by Outlook REST API, in result to the attempt to subscribe (POST to url : `https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/users/{id}/subscriptions`.

Comment: Clear, thanks. So Outlook REST API is unable to make an HTTPS connection to your server. Besides TLS versions this can also depend on the hash functions, key exchange algorithms and ciphers supported by either side. Heroko has disabled TLS 1.0 since August 31 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1195) so that can't be it.
Is your SSL endpoint in Heroku using a self-signed certificate?
Heroku suggests using curl to test your endpoint: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint#testing-ssl

Comment: I found the solution thanks to your help ! It was indeed a problem of ssl configuration between heroku and cloudflare. SSL was not enable between them, only between cloudflare and the enduser. Now it's ok !